# Why am I not getting error here while I put wrong email or password

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, fetch-api

I am trying to put wrong password and email and its not sending error message and also its login and let it enter in main page so can you help me to show error message while I put wrong password and email.

I am trying to put wrong password and email and its not sending error message and also its login and let it enter in main page so can you help me to show error message while I put wrong password and email.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Swal from "sweetalert2";
import Cookies from "universal-cookie";
import head from "../img/head.png";
import login from "../img/login.svg";

export class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      email: "",
      password: "",
      submitted: false
    };
    this.cookies = new Cookies();
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

 
  handleChange(e) {
    const name = e.target.name;
    const value = e.target.value;
    this.setState(prevstate => {
      const newState = { ...prevstate };
      newState[name] = value;
      return newState;
    });
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    this.setState({ submitted: true });
    if (this.state.email && this.state.password) {
      this.fetchUserData();
    }
  }

  async fetchUserData() {
    Swal.fire({
      title: "Logging in Process",
      showCancelButton: false,
      showConfirmButton: false,
      onBeforeOpen: () => {
        Swal.showLoading();
      }
    });

    const requestData = {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({
        email: this.state.email,
        password: this.state.password
      }),
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
    };

    const request = await fetch(
      "https://tardis-back.herokuapp.com/auth/sign_in",
      requestData
    );
    const response = await request;

    this.cookies.set("Access-Token", response.headers.get("Access-Token"));
    this.cookies.set("Client", response.headers.get("Client"));
    this.cookies.set("Uid", response.headers.get("Uid"));
    this.cookies.set("Expiry", response.headers.get("Expiry"));

    var error = true;

    if (response.success === undefined) {
      error = false;
    } else {
      error = true;
    }

    if (!error) {
      Swal.fire({
        title: "Loggedin",
        type: "success",
        showConfirmButton: false,
        timer: 1000
      }).then(login => {
        if (login.dismiss === Swal.DismissReason.timer) {
          window.sessionStorage.setItem("isLoggedIn", true);
          window.location.href = "/";
        }
      });
    } else {
      Swal.fire({
        timer: 1000,
        title: "Logging Error",
        type: "error",
        text: "Your entered Wrong Email or Password"
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <section class="login-block ">
        <div class="containe container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-5 id login-sec ">
              <img src={head} alt="logo" style={{ height: "60px" }}></img>{" "}
              <br></br>
              <span className="headd" style={{ fontSize: "13px" }}>
                SOFT BIKE
              </span>
              <h5 className=" text-dark text-left log">LOG IN</h5>
              <form class="login-form">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label
                    for="exampleInputEmail1"
                    class=""
                    style={{
                      color: "rgba(19, 183, 96, 1.0)",
                      fontSize: "13px",
                      opacity: "0.7"
                    }}
                  >
                    Username
                  </label>
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    class="form-control"
                    placeholder=""
                    name="email"
                    value={this.state.email}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                  />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label
                    for="exampleInputPassword1"
                    class=""
                    style={{
                      color: "rgba(19, 183, 96, 1.0)",
                      fontSize: "13px",
                      opacity: "0.7"
                    }}
                  >
                    Password
                  </label>
                  <input
                    type="password"
                    class="form-control"
                    placeholder=""
                    name="password"
                    value={this.state.password}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                  />
                </div>
                <p
                  style={{
                    fontSize: "14px",
                    opacity: "0.6",
                    fontWeight: "400",
                    fontFamily: "'Roboto', Helvetica, Arial, serif"
                  }}
                >
                  Forget Password ?
                </p>
                <br></br>
                <button
                  type="submit"
                  value="Login"
                  onClick={this.handleSubmit}
                  class="btn btn-login btn-block text-white font-weight-bolder box "
                  style={{
                    background: "rgba(19, 183, 96, 1.0)",
                    padding: "10px",
                    boxShadow: "0px 8px 25px -7px #c0c0c0",
                    borderRadius: "4px"
                  }}
                >
                  START
                </button>
              </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-7 banner-sec">
              <div
                id="carouselExampleIndicators"
                class="carousel slide"
                data-ride="carousel"
              >
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                  <li
                    data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"
                    data-slide-to="0"
                    class="active"
                  ></li>
                </ol>
                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                  <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img
                      class="d-block img-fluid"
                      src={login}
                      alt="First slide"
                    />
                    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                      <div class="banner-text">
                        <h2>SOFT BIKE</h2>
                        <p>
                          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
                          elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
                          dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
                          nostrud exercitation
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    );
  }
}

export default Login;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For wrong email + pwd scenarios, your API returns a 401 status code (As expected).

> But the way your handle this error is wrong in your code.

As per `fetch` documentation - [visit page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Checking_that_the_fetch_was_successful)

> An accurate check for a successful fetch() would include checking that the promise resolved, then checking that the Response.ok property has a value of true.

So, change this line in your code -

```js
if (response.success === undefined) {
```

To something like this -

```js
if (response.ok) {
```

And you would get the login error.

A live sandbox is created here to play with - https://codesandbox.io/embed/58116788-handle-fetch-error-uzxvg